# Hide custom code at home page in woocommerce

Tags: php, html, wordpress, woocommerce

How can I remove this code on the homepage

This is my code:

```
<?php 
    if(!is_home()){

   <div class="product-hover">

        <div class="product-buttons">

            <?php woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart(); ?>

            <?php echo mts_wishlist_button(); ?>

            <a href="#" data-product-id="<?php echo esc_attr( $product->get_id() ); ?>" class="quick-look-link button"><i class="fa fa-search"></i><span><?php _e( 'Quick Look', MTS_THEME_TEXTDOMAIN );?></span></a>

            <a href="<?php echo esc_url( get_the_permalink() ); ?>" class="button"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i></a>

        </div>

    </div> } ?>
```

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: seems that you are missing a closing php tag '?>' after  if(!is_home()){ . Also the final curly bracket at the bottom needs to be wrapped in php tags.

Comment: change line 2 to this:   if(!is_home()){ ?>      and the last line to this: </div> <?php } ?>

Comment: How kind are you to help me.